# Textarea with initial auto height by content with pure CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've been looking for a simple CSS solution to make a texarea match height to its content.

I DO NOT want an auto resizing textarea that changes as you type. I have a textarea with text already in it and I want it to match the content.

Is there any way to do this using CSS?

Comment: No, because, by definition, a `textarea` isn't sized according to its content.

Comment: If the text is already in it, why don't you just set a static height based on that text?

Comment: I can do it with code but I'm asking if it's possible with css. All evidence points against this, alas.

Comment: You can set the height with CSS(which is code).

Answer (score 1):

No, because, by definition, a `textarea` isn't sized according to its content.

You could however, use a `<div contenteditable="true"></div>` and style it to look and act like a `textarea`.

```css
.textarea {border:1px solid #e0e0e0; max-height:100px; overflow-y:scroll;}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" class="textarea">jdsklf ;askf; fs;dlfkj sad;flkasdj f;laskfj as;lfkajsd f;lasdkfj asl;dkfj sad;lfkasjd f;laskdjf a;sldfkj asdf;lkasdjf ;lasdkfj asd;lfkjsad f;laksdjf ;alsdkfjs ad;lfkjsad f;lksadjf ;lasdkfjasdl;fk jasdl;fkj asdf;lksadj f;lsadkfj sad;lfkjsd f;lksadjf; lsadkfjsda;lfk jsd;lfk jsdf</div>
```

Comment: That's a cool and creative solution. But the I rather write some JS than style a div to look and behave exactly as my already styled textarea. Thanks though, it seems that I got my answer :).

Comment: @BernardGritsmiller Your question made it seem as if you didn't want a JavaScript solution - only CSS solutions.

Comment: @BernardGritsmiller The JavaScript solution would be difficult because you can't get the height of the text and then set the textarea to that height.

Comment: What I actually wanted is a CSS property. Oh well.

Comment: @BernardGritsmiller That wasn't clear either. In any case, I don't see a JavaScript solution here, short of counting the characters in the field and then writing some algorithm to see how many characters would fit on a line of the field (taking the font-style and font-size into account) and then determining how many lines of text are in the box (based on the box's width) and then setting the height of the box to that.

Comment: Its possible. See my answer.

Comment: "I have a textarea with text already in it and I want it to match the content" OP says he already has the content. And if you want to make it dynamic, a little js will do ya.

Comment: @Geuis That's a lot of work to do exactly what my answer does with 2 lines of code and it requires that the content be duplicated (not very DRY).

Comment: @ScottMarcus Yeah I'm not disagreeing. Just showing that a pure css solution is possible for the textarea, as OP asked. I personally wouldn't do it this way either, but it is possible.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I thank you again. No need to take it personal.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a 100% css way to do it.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BxLMKK

Note that for this demo I did a simple 2-column layout just to provide context, but the actual important part is just in the `.textbox-mimic` div.

html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <div class="textarea-mimic">
      <span>
        Here's some text that's already here. Here's some text that's already here. Here's some text that's already here. Here's some text that's already here. Here's some text that's already here. Here's some text that's already here.  Here's some text that's already here. Here's some text that's already here. Here's some text that's already here. Here's some text that's already here.
      </span>
    <textarea>Here's some text that's already here. Here's some text that's already here. Here's some text that's already here. Here's some text that's already here. Here's some text that's already here. Here's some text that's already here.  Here's some text that's already here. Here's some text that's already here. Here's some text that's already here. Here's some text that's already here.
        </textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    Some things over here
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  outline: 2px solid #000;
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container > div {
  flex: 1;
  outline: 1px solid #cc00cc;
  padding: 8px;
}

.container > div > .textarea-mimic {
  position: relative;
}
.container > div > .textarea-mimic > span {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.container > div > .textarea-mimic > textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  font: inherit;
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: none;
/*   display: none; */
}
```

So basically what's happening here is that we're populating the content of the textarea and another sibling (span in this case) with the same content. The styling of the text area is updated to have the same font, padding, etc as the div. Depending on your specific needs, you just updated these as you see fit. But its critical they match so that the spacing and layout are identical.

Then we set some properties for the textarea to make it position absolute and to adopt the dimensions of the parent. Finally, the content of the `.textarea-mimic > span` is set to `visibility: hidden`. This allows the dimensions to be filled out while only showing the text area. Toggle the visibility property off and the `display: none` of the textarea to see it in action.

Also note that if you would like this to update in realtime, some simple javascript that updates the content of the hidden text based on the textarea should make it dynamic.

Comment: I tried to add some text. Textarea didn't resize automatically.